# Automatically set Light and Dark Themes to interchange at Given times

Tags: scripting, desktop-environment, theme

I have a specific setting for my light theme and darker theme to use at night.How can I automate the interchange process.?

Comment: Use `cron` to rotate in your daytime and nighttime configuration files accordingly?

Comment: @DopeGhoti what is `cron` ?

Comment: `cron` is the most common and effective way to schedule tasks on a POSIX (e. g. Unix or Linux) system.  You set up a list of specific intervals (ranging in complexity from "every hour at x:05" to "every six minutes from 4:00 to 4:24 every Thursday in October") and a task to do at the specified time (e. g. "run this script" or "run this command").  See the manual page `man cron` for detailed information.

Comment: what OS? which desktop environment are you using?   gnome? kde? xfce? lxde? other?

Comment: Ubuntu distro......Unity Desktop environment with compiz WM